# Why I can access my contract in one function but not another one

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am sorry if the title is a bit confusing.

I am working on an Ethereum blockchain with a smart contract.

```
App={
 createVoter1: function(){
        App.contracts.Voting.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            // use the contract function createBallot
            var college = $("#college1").text();
            var major = $("#major1").text();
            var expirydate = $("#expirydate").text();
            var serialnumber = $("#serialnumber1").text();
            instance.createVoter(web3.eth.accounts[0],major,college,expirydate,serialnumber,"",[]);
        })
    },
    ifVoterAddressExists: function(){
      App.contracts.Voting.deployed().then(function(instance){
        instance.ifVoterAddressExists(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
      })
    }
}
```

I skipped some code before the createVoter1 function. The problem is, the createVoter1 function can use the contract's function successfully. However, when I use the ifVoterAddressExists, there is a warning of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deployed' of undefined**. Can I know if there are any possible solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is executed outside deployment. You need to wait for the contract to be deployed first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you further explain how can I "wait for the contract to be deployed"?